# mpmovieplayercontroller fast forward and rewind buttons

Tags: ios, ios7

This is question is duplicate of question :

[iOS 7 MPMoviePlayerController seek forward button brings the video to the End and displays Black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570838/ios-7-mpmovieplayercontroller-seek-forward-button-brings-the-video-to-the-end-an)

since I did not get proper answer, posting it again.

Issue is : in MPMoviePlayerController fast forward and rewind buttons work only when user does the long press. If user does the single click, blank screen appears in video screen. How to disable single click on these buttons ?

Comment: i think a better solution would be to trigger double click on single click

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Even with double click, the behavior is same. Only for Long press it works fine.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393539/long-press-event-on-button

Comment: also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876202/uitapgesturerecognizer-single-tap-and-double-tap you may need a requireGestureRecognizerToFail for the singleclick and double click

Answer (score 0):

The best option is probably to not use the standard controls and add your own.

This page gives detailed information on how to do that:
http://wosimei.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/how-to-custom-a-ios-movie-player-control-bar/

You can then control the playback using the methods in the `MPMediaPlayback` protocol.

Comment: you should know better than to post a link-only. show the code. links break!